# Why @Inject does not work in spring 4?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, dao, autowired, inject

I work on Spring 4.1.7 configuring with hibernate sesstionFactory . When I use `@Autowire` it works well:

```
 @Repository
public class UserDao implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;


public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    Assert.notNull(sessionFactory);
}

public void save(User user) {

}

public void persist(User user) {

}

public User findByUsername(String username) {
    List<User> users = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from User where username=:username").setParameter("username", username).list();
    if (users.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return users.get(0);
    }
}
}
```

But when I change it to `@Inject` it does not work and fires `IllegalArgumentException assertion failed` the `sessionFactory` is null.
Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Why change? Do you have the inject api on your classpath when running else nothing is going to happen

Comment: If we had the stacktrace / logs we could see what is going on?